# How can I get javascript value and store to html<input>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a rating to my system,  please help me to get the value from javascript and store in html.

Here is my js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#stars').on('starrr:change', function(e, value){
  $('#count').html(value); });
```

The js is working fine, it return the number of rating.

```
<h4>You gave a rating of <span id="count">0</span> star(s)</h4>
```

I want to get the result of id = count and store in html input named rate.

```
<input type="hidden" name="rate" value="">
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Use jQuery's [name selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Comment: `$('input[name="rate"]').val($('#count').text())`

Comment: thank you! it works godbless

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example, hope this helps.

```js
document.getElementById('rate').addEventListener('input', function() {
  document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = this.value; 
});
```

```html
<h4>You gave a rating of <span id="count">0</span> star(s)</h4>
<input id="rate" type="number" name="rate" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that instead of .html you can use .val().text() for this case. You're wanting the value right?

Answer (score 0):

Select the input box using Jquery Selector `$('input[name=rate]')` and assign value to it.

`$('input[name=rate]').val($('#count').html());`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name=rate]').val(starcount);
```

Where starcount is the variable that holds the number of stars